# Does there exists a continuous injection from $R$ to torus $T^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Does there exists a continuous injection $f:R\longrightarrow T^2$?

$T^2=S^1\times S^1$ is a torus embedded naturally in $R^3$?

EDIT: I want the continous injection of the form $f(x)=(g(x),h(x))$ where $g(x):R\longrightarrow S^1$ is a universal covering and $h(x):R\longrightarrow S^1$ is any given continuous map.

Comment: There is already a continuous injection from $\mathbb R$ to the interval $(0,1)$.  Are you sure there are no other constraints on your function?

Comment: @ErickWong Yes there are conditions. I have edited the question.

Comment: You can take something like $f(x)=(\exp(ix),\exp(i\arctan(x)))$. The idea is to make $g$ wrap around its $S^1$ using the universal covering, while $h$ just moves increasingly on a little arc that doesn't go all the away around to not risk self-intersection. In this case, the arc from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: If $h$ is any **given** cotinuous map, this will not work in general. Just consider constant $h$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Let $\xi$ be an irrational number. Define
$$f(t) = (e^{t i},e^{\xi t i}) .$$

Both $g(t) = e^{ti}, h(t) =e^{\xi t i}$ are universal coverings.

Now let $f(t) = f(s)$. Then $ti-si = 2k\pi i$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $\xi t i - \xi s i = 2l\pi i$ for some $l \in \mathbb Z$. We conclude $2k\pi \xi i = 2l \pi i$, i.e. $k\xi = l$. This is possible only when $k = l = 0$. Thus $s = t$.